# Safari Web Push Notifications Stopped Working

Tags: macos, push-notification, safari, web-push

About 2,5 weeks ago our web site push notifications in Safari stopped working. Initially we received an error server side, but this is no longer showing.

We can see the PushPackage.zip being downloaded after Safari prompts the user if they want to receive notifications. But after that nothing.

In our client side code the request with `default` comes in to request the device using `window.safari.pushNotification.requestPermission`. However in 9/10 calls nothing happens after this.

```
const checkRemotePermission = (permissionData) => {
    if (permissionData.permission === 'default') {
        // This is a new web service URL and its validity is unknown.
        window.safari.pushNotification.requestPermission(
            'https://host/push',
            'pushid',
            {user: ****},
            checkRemotePermission
        );
    } else if (permissionData.permission === 'denied') {
        // User does not want 
    } else if (permissionData.permission === 'granted') {
        // register the device
    }
};
```

On 1/10 the call comes back as expected with `granted` and push notifications work. But without this call coming in, push notifications simply don't work.

To our knowledge nothing changed in our server and client code. We regenerated the web push certificated and we even requested a new AuthToken, recreated and PushPackages and used the latest G4 certificate.

All leading to the same result.

It feels like the call that Safari does with the PushPackage.zip file goes to the Void...

Any help would be great. We are lost as something that worked for 2,5 years stopped working without any traceable changes.

We have gone through Apple Support, but after talking to 3 departments and they all sending me back to the previous department I hope someone can help me, and more import, our clients here.